# Prove that $\mathring{(X\backslash A)}=X\backslash \overline{A}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $\mathring{(X\backslash A)}=X\backslash \overline{A}$. When proving that $\mathring{(X\backslash A)}\subset X\backslash \overline{A}$ I am having trouble when $A$ is an open set. It is obvious that if $x \in \mathring{(X\backslash A)}$ then $x \in X$ and $x \notin A$, but I feel like $x \notin \overline{A}$ is not that obvious and I have to do something to prove it.
I am trying to prove that if $x \in \overline{A}$ and $x \notin A$ then $x \notin \mathring{(X\backslash A)}$, but I don't know how to work this out. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ belongs to RHS, which we denote by $U$, then $U$ is an open set containing $x$. But $A \subset \overline A$ so $U=X\setminus \overline A \subset X\setminus A$.   So $x$ belongs to LHS.

Let $x$ belong to LHS. There is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subset X\setminus A$. Since there is an open set containing $x$ which contains no point of $A$ it follows that $x $ cannot belong to $\overline A$. So $x$ belongs to RHS.

Comment: I don't understand the "containing $A$ which contains no point of $A$" bit. If a set contains $A$, then it must contain every point of $A$, so I don't understand yor reasoning

Comment: @kubo There was a typo. I have corrected it.